# Dynamic Menu with cocos2d for ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Dear stackoverflow community,

I have a simple menu that have to be dynamics. With dynamics I mean that I have a different number of element each time that I open that menu.

so, I have this NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *answerList = [[NSArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<countAnswers; i++){

    CCLabelTTF *labelAnswer = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:answer fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:40];        
    CCMenuItemLabel * MenuItemAnswer = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:labelAnswer target:self selector:@selector(vedidimorire)];
    [answerList addObject:MenuItemAnswer];


}
```

the code is simplified, but what is important is that I have an array with various CCMenuItem. 
Now I wont create the menuItems with this elements

```
CCMenu * myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: ????? ];
```

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot in advance for the answer!
Benza

Comment: NSMutableArray * answerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; Also, don't forget to release it when you are done with it. Are you sure that the method "menuWithItems:" takes an NSMutableArray as input?

Comment: thanks MSgambel. The method menuWIthItems doesn't takes an NSMutableArray as input. In fact my question is: If I can't use an array, how can I add item to the menu dinamically?

Comment: Init CCMenu with nil items, then iterate over array and use [menu addChild:menuItem] http://stackoverflow.com/a/9303191/317928

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `answerList` mutable array, there are `CCMenuItemLabel` objects.

Now if you want to create menus, first you have to count how many answers are there in `answerList` and then create corresponding `CCMenu` with each these items in `[CCMenu menuWithItems:`.

First determine the minimum and maximum answers that can be in `answerList` array.
Let minAnswer = 3 and maxAnswer = 6
Then,

```
int currentAnswerCount = [answerList count];
CCmenu  myMenu;

if (currentAnswerCount == minAnswer) {
myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:[answerList objectAtIndex:0], [answerList objectAtIndex:1], [answerList objectAtIndex:2]];
}
else if (currentAnswerCount == minAnwer + 1 {
myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:[answerList objectAtIndex:0], [answerList objectAtIndex:1], [answerList objectAtIndex:2], [answerList objectAtIndex:3]];
}
..
.. 
upto maxAnswer.

[self addChild:myMenu];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I would like to have a really dynamic method. In this way I have to know a priori the max and the min of my answers. Since I have to take this answer from a database I have no way to know the minimum and the maximum

Comment: can u tell me for what purpose the menu is. I mean I guessed that the menu was for game, isn't it? Or is it any database related app?

Comment: yep it is for a game, in one of the screens I have to show randomly some questions with answers. Question&Answers are retrieved from a database and I don't know the number of the answer. Yes I can suppose that probably I will not have more than 10 answer, but who knows? maybe in the future one question will have 11 answer. 
Now I am trying with the va_list, if doesn't work I think that I'll follow the second advice of the first answer: I will use clickable labels.

Comment: well.. if you don't know in exact the number of answers then making your own custom class without using CCMenu would be great choice. All the best.

Comment: yep, I'll do like this, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you have a few options here.

You should be able to pass a va_list into CCMenu
Read this for more info:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

otherwise,

Simply, don't use CCmenu.
Make a custom class which can handle touch events.

Hope this helps

Adam

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a while ago and there is a really easy way to do it. Just add your CCMenuItem as a child of your CCMenu in each loop. Replace [answerList addObject:MenuItemAnswer]; with [myMenu addChild:MenuItemAnswer];, get rid of the MenuItemAnswer array, and create myMenu with this code: CCMenu * menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil]; and don't forget to add this menu as a child of another CCNode.

Comment: This answer perfectly solved my issue when trying to create a custom keyboard for my iPhone app. For some reason though when adding CCMenuItems as children to the CCMenu, the last CCMenuItem added  gets centred. Why would this be happening?