# How do you properly create a va_list dynamically at runtime for Cocos2D CCMenu menuWithItems?

Tags: iphone, c, cocos2d-iphone, variadic-functions

I'm having a hell of a time with the CCMenu class. To create a menu with this class it forces you to call a method called initWithItems, which takes a va_list. I need to generate this list at runtime, and I read that creating a C array and passing that can function just as va_list does under the covers, only it is failing.

I have an NSArray of items I want in the va_list, and these items are a SUBCLASS of CCMenuItem, the class that menuWithItems is expecting in the va_list. If you hardcode this list at compile time, it works fine, but my attempt to create this list dynamically is not working. What is wrong with this? MenuItemButton is a CCMenuItem subclass.

```
NSArray *menuItems = [self getMenuItemsArray]; // Returns an NSArray of MenuItemButtons 
MenuItemButton *argList = (MenuItemButton *)malloc( sizeof(MenuItemButton *) * [menuItems count] );
[menuItems getObjects:(id *)argList];
CCMenuAdvanced* menu = [CCMenuAdvanced menuWithItems:argList];
```

This crashes at runtime, BAD_ACCESS. I know the va_list is supposed to be null terminated, I don't know if that is the case with my code here after calling getObjects, or if that is even the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply initialize the menu using nil.  For example,

```
CCMenu * myMenu = [CCMenuAdvanced menuWithItems:nil];
```

Then say you have a dynamic list of strings that you loaded at runtime, try....

```
// replace this with a dynamically loaded array of items...
NSArray* dynamicArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"red", @"blue", @"green", nil];


for (NSString* item in dynamicArray)
{
    CCMenuItem *menuItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: item target: self     selector:@selector(menuCallback:)];
    [myMenu addChild:menuItem];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`va_list` isn't always an array. With 32-bit gcc, it is, with 64-bit it isn't. Don't rely on it.

`va_list` is generated by a function that gets a variable number of arguments:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
void f(int x, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, x);
    function_that_wants_va(va);
    va_end(va);
}
void g(void) {
    f(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Comment: The code is for the iphone only. From what you wrote, the question I asked was, how do you call function f at RUNTIME when you don't know how many arguments you have at compile time. Do I need to change the way I ask the question?

Comment: I don't know if there's iPhone specific stuff. with C in general, I don't know a good way. You can always pass the maximum number (extra arguments don't matter). You can also go for this ugly thing: `switch(n){ case 1: f(1,a[0]);break; case 2: f(2,a[0],a[1]);break; ...}`

Comment: Actually I can't do that, the number of cases is unknown, its based on how many files match a regex from a directory file listing. Thanks for trying though man, appreciate it!